Leaflet Control-Layers-Expanded text not aligned to the checkbox
I have a Leaflet map with some base maps and layers but there's a bug inside the layer control popup. When opened, the checkbox/radio to select the options are not aligned to the label.
Here's an example image
This is the JavaScript code that manages the layer controls:
    var baseMaps = {
    "OSM": lyr_osm,
    "ARCGIS": lyr_arcgis,
    "Satellite": lyr_satellite,
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "Apple": marker_1,
    "Orange": marker_2,
    "Melon": marker_3,
    "Pear": marker_4,
    "Peach": marker_5,
    "Grapes": marker_6,
};

var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

How can I fix it? I tried several CSS editing but nothing worked. The class should be leaflet-control-layers-expanded
Thanks

Looks like you might add display:block; on <span> and <input>. You need provide more info.

@Shuo That control popup is automatically managed by Leaflet/Javascript, so I can't add  and there aren't any . I added JS code in the post

<span>(the label) and <input>(the checkbox/radio) were created by leaflet but they are still in same page, so your css styles will affect these elements.
